# Letter writing - university admissions

Tags: correspondence

I am new to English language. I drafted an e-mail to university requesting the information regarding my offer letter. Also, how can I politely ask to make things done quickly, so that I may apply for visa well in time.

Subject: International postgraduate applicant: unconditional offer status

Dear Sir,

I am writing to know the status of my request for issue of an unconditional offer of MSc Electrical Engineering course, starting in October, 2103.

I have submitted all relevant documents by an email on June 14, 2013.

May I kindly request the information regarding the expected date by which CAS number and the unconditional offer will be issued.

Thanking you.

Warm regards,

Xyz Abc (Application reference no...)

Comment: Hi Tanay, welcome to ELL! I'm glad to see that you've gotten assistance, but in the future I would ask that when you post a proofreading question you take care to identify specific areas of concern. If you have a specific area you're not sure about and would like assistance, that's perfectly acceptable. But unfortunately proofreading questions are off topic unless that is provided. Thanks, and welcome again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I would make for a formal email:

> Dear Sir **or Madam**,
>
> I am writing to <del>know</del> **ask for confirmation of** the status of my request for **the** issue of an unconditional offer of **a place on your** MSc Electrical Engineering course, starting in October<del>, 2103</del> **2013**.
>
> I have submitted all **the** relevant documents by <del>an</del> email on June 14, 2013.
>
> <del>May I kindly request</del> **Could you please send me** the information regarding the expected date by which **the** CAS number and <del>the</del> unconditional offer will be issued<del>.</del>**?**
>
> **I would appreciate any efforts you are able to make in expediting this process, so that I am able to submit my visa application in good time.**
>
> Thank<del>ing</del> you **for your assistance**.
>
> Warm regards,
>
> Xyz Abc (Application reference no...)

Caveat: I am a native *British* English speaker. It's possible that cultural norms in e.g. the US are different in ways that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Proof reading questions are off-topic. Rather than answering then, you should flag them to get them closed (flag >> it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate… >> off-topic because... >>  Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. See: Alternative websites for proofreading).

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: Thank you a lot. That really helped me.